# How to access a response value titled "self"?

Tags: jsonnet

I am using jsonnet to process a response that is structured like so:

```
{
    "resources": [
        {
           "response_body": {
                "id": "test_id",
                "key": "test_key",
                "self": "https://someurl.com/test/1234"
            }
      ........
```

I am attempting to process hte response with the following jsonnet:

```
local result = std.parseJson(std.extVar('result'));
local resource = result.resources[0];
{
  result_fields: {
    issue_url: resource.response_body.self,
    issue: resource.response_body.id
  }
}
```

But it's throwing the error:

```
JsonnetTokenType.IDENTIFIER expected, got 'self'
```

How would I go about access the `self` value from my response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`self` is a reserved word (it's a reference to the current object in scope), if you'd still needed to use 'self' (as it's e.g. enforced by the JSON structure in `result`), you could then do:

```
local result = std.parseJson(std.extVar('result'));
local resource = result.resources[0];
{
  result_fields: {
    issue_url: resource.response_body['self'],
    issue: resource.response_body.id
  }
}
```

Nevertheless, if possible to use a different key/field name there I'd strongly suggest finding another name.

Comment: Finding another name is not an option.  Thanks for the info!